# This version of visual studio is incompatible

Tags: visual-studio

I have downloaded a project from web and i am not able to open the project. It says the project is incompatible with the current edition.

I have used VS 2012 desktop express, 2013 desktop express and latest 2015 desktop express editions for the same but unable to open it. I am perplexed as to know whats happening.

```
 please note: The test project InstaSharp.Tests.csproj is opening.
 InstaSharp.csproj is not opening.
```

**error message:**

```
 src\InstaSharp\InstaSharp.csproj: The application which this project type is based on was not found. Please try this link for further information: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=299083&projecttype=786C830F-07A1-408B-BD7F-6EE04809D6DB
```

This is the project file. It says vs2013 but when i try to open the file using vs2013 its simply not happening.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
# Visual Studio 2013
VisualStudioVersion = 12.0.30723.0
MinimumVisualStudioVersion = 10.0.40219.1
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "InstaSharp",   "src\InstaSharp\InstaSharp.csproj", "{CD3EA37A-6C9D-4B74-A2A8-1483259FB1B8}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "InstaSharp.Tests",  "src\InstaSharp.Tests\InstaSharp.Tests.csproj", "{32025768-5A2A-4085-A95E-D6B5E616034C}"
EndProject
Global
GlobalSection(SolutionConfigurationPlatforms) = preSolution
    Debug|Any CPU = Debug|Any CPU
    Release|Any CPU = Release|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(ProjectConfigurationPlatforms) = postSolution
    {CD3EA37A-6C9D-4B74-A2A8-1483259FB1B8}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {CD3EA37A-6C9D-4B74-A2A8-1483259FB1B8}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {CD3EA37A-6C9D-4B74-A2A8-1483259FB1B8}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {CD3EA37A-6C9D-4B74-A2A8-1483259FB1B8}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
    {32025768-5A2A-4085-A95E-D6B5E616034C}.Debug|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Debug|Any CPU
    {32025768-5A2A-4085-A95E-D6B5E616034C}.Debug|Any CPU.Build.0 = Debug|Any CPU
    {32025768-5A2A-4085-A95E-D6B5E616034C}.Release|Any CPU.ActiveCfg = Release|Any CPU
    {32025768-5A2A-4085-A95E-D6B5E616034C}.Release|Any CPU.Build.0 = Release|Any CPU
EndGlobalSection
GlobalSection(SolutionProperties) = preSolution
    HideSolutionNode = FALSE
EndGlobalSection
EndGlobal
```

Comment: What error do you receive?

Comment: Strange. I've just opened the project using Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 and no errors thrown. Are you sure that your Visual Studio supports C#? You could try opening the create new project windows and see if Visual C# is listed there

Comment: I am using many projects in C#. How do i know which update of vs2013 i am using?

Comment: This should atleast open in Microsoft VS 2015 but it doesnot.

Comment: Most projects require Visual Studio Professional Edition, while now you can get Community Edition. Forget about Express Edition as rarely a serious developer uses that.

Comment: will downloading community edition help the cause?